# Web App for storing customer inventory (PHP Open Source pref)

Tags: web-apps, document-management, information-management, inventory

I hope I'm in the right place when I'm asking this, but I'm looking for something that can store client/customer inventory such as:

Computers/Workstations

- ID/Tag
- Make/Model
- HD Space
- IP Address
- etc.

Servers

- ID/Tag
- Type
- HD Space
- Memory
- etc.

Routers/Modems

- ID/Tag
- Manufacturer/Model
- Type
- etc.

After storing, I should be able to pull up everything for a specific client or category.  I would also prefer it to be open source/PHP so I could add it to a previous project. I picture it being similar to a DMS, but I'm not 100% sure!

Comment: @chenmunka currently I'm running an apache web server which has a custom HR application.  It'd be nice to add to that, but I'm open for more than just that.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://inventory.sourceforge.net/) gets a five-star rating on SourceForge:

> Inventory tool for the system administrator written in PHP with MySQL
>   as a backend. The idea is to create a database driven system with a
>   web front end that will allow the administrator to index, associate
>   link and maintain all of the hardware and software.

[image: Inventory UI]